# Is aexp.intent.action special?

Tags: android, plugins

Every example I find of anyone implementing plugins in android seems to use "aexp.intent.action." as the prefix for their invented intent string.

Is that string special somehow, or is everyone simply copying the [My Life with Android](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/plugins.html) blog entry and doing plugins the same way?

I'm just curious here :-).

Comment: +1 for asking the same exact question I was about to ask. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every example I find of anyone implementing plugins in android seems to use "aexp.intent.action." as the prefix for their invented intent string.

Um, OK.

> Is that string special somehow

No.

> is everyone simply copying the My Life with Android blog entry and doing plugins the same way?

No.

Every example *that you looked at* apparently is "simply copying the My Life with Android blog entry and doing plugins the same way". And, the authors of those other examples presumably are not using that action string in production -- you want your plugins to use *unique* action strings, so they can be identified as plugins for your host app (as opposed to somebody else's app).

Production-grade plugins do not necessarily use anything from that blog post, let alone the action string. Not that there's anything wrong with that blog post, but it is far from the One and Only Way to Implement Plugins in Android.

Comment: True. It was every one I looked at used that prefix, but it was only because I found fantastic numbers of references that I asked the question :-). And most of them were unique strings, but they all used the same prefix.

Comment: @user1160711: ::shrug:: Your question was the first time in over four years that I have ever encountered `aexp.intent.action`. I'm not even sure what "aexp" stands for, beyond American Express. I would recommend that you use something based on your app's own package name (e.g., `com.commonsware.myapp.intent.action`), for mostly-guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to replace `aexp` with `com.commonsware.myapp`.